# replace mockito function between tests in same class in scala/mockito/play

Tags: scala, junit, mockito, playframework-2.1

I am running tests on my scala with play and mockito.
This is my code:

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class ProductServiceTests extends Specification
with ProductRepositoryComponent
with ProductServiceComponentImpl
with Mockito
 {

  val productRepository = mock[ProductRepository]
  val productId = "d3d08285-512f-46a6-811f-1abeb94ebb98"
  val product:Product = new Product(Option(productId), "default name", "default description", new References(Some("1"), Some("1"), Some("1"), Some("1")))
  val language = "en_US"
  val tenantId = ""

  def mockStuff = {
    productRepository.addProduct(any[String], any[String], any[Product]) returns
    product.id.get

    productRepository.updateProduct(any[String], any[String], any[Product]) returns
    product.id.get
  }

  step(mockStuff)

  "ProductService" should {
    "add minimal product to product repository" in {
      val result = productService.addProduct(language, tenantId, product)
      result mustNotEqual null
      result must beAnInstanceOf[DTOResponse[String]]
      val resultAsStr = result.asInstanceOf[DTOResponse[String]].get
      resultAsStr.length mustEqual 36 //Guid length
      resultAsStr mustEqual productId
    }

     //How can i override addProduct - So that from now on, it will use the exception throwing add Product.. (commented one)
    "update product in repository" in {
      val result = productService.addProduct("he_IL", tenantId, product)
      result mustNotEqual null
      result must beAnInstanceOf[DTOResponse[String]]
      val resultAsStr = result.asInstanceOf[DTOResponse[String]].get
      resultAsStr.length mustEqual 36 //Guid length
      resultAsStr mustEqual productId
    }
  }  
}
```

I have 2 **in** inside the should.. How can i override addProduct method for the 2nd in ?

My problem is i want to simulate 2 addProduct functions, One will be ok, the other one will be invalid since the Id already exists..

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest extracting the `productRepository.addProduct ...` from mockStuff and put it in each of the corresponding "in" with the appropriate params for each test

Comment: What do you mean by extract the method and put within the in. ? Can u give sample as answer? Thanks

Comment: you example references tons of types which are not defined making it quite a pain to rewrite ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will helpful for someone..

When defining mockStuff, One should implement the same method over and over, but the parameters are different on every time, then when calling that method, supply the params points to the implementation you wrote in the function.
Another issue that should be taken in mind is that only **RuntimeException** should be thrown.
 e.g in my sample, when i put He_IL i wish to throw exception, so i call my function with the string "He_IL" and then i will get the "getProduct" that throws exception:

```
with Mockito
 {
  val productRepository = mock[ProductRepository]
  val productId = "d3d08285-512f-46a6-811f-1abeb94ebb98"
  val product:Product = new Product(Option(productId), "default name", "default description", new References(Some("1"), Some("1"), Some("1"), Some("1")))
  val language = "en_US"
  val tenantId = ""

  def mockStuff = {
    productRepository.addProduct(any[AddProductRequest]) returns
    product.id.get

    productRepository.addProduct(AddProductRequest("He_IL",tenantId, product)) throws new RuntimeException("Language must be english !! !!")        
  }

step(mockStuff)

  "ProductService" should {
    "add product with only required fields to product repository" in {
      val result = productService.addProduct(AddProductRequest(language, tenantId, product))
      result mustNotEqual null
      result must beAnInstanceOf[DTOResponse[String]]
      val resultAsStr = result.asInstanceOf[DTOResponse[String]].get
     resultAsStr mustEqual productId
    }


    "add product when getting exception from product repository" in {
      val result = productService.addProduct(AddProductRequest("He_IL", tenantId, product))
      result mustNotEqual null
      result must beAnInstanceOf[DTOResponse[String]]
      val resultAsStr = result.asInstanceOf[DTOResponse[String]].get
     resultAsStr mustEqual productId
    }
```